# How to Insert Other Language(Like French,Chinese) Characters From ASP.NET Gridview to the Oracle Table

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, oracle

I am having some tables data which is having French, Chinese language characters.

ex: ENTRÉÉ D25 SBS RAL 7035 MG

I can able to show these tables data in gridview with same language and i am able to generate the query based on number of rows from gridview dynamically which is correct.

If insert from SQL Developer tool it is inserting correctly, if the query is executed from .net it is going in English characters.

Ex: ENTRÉÉ D25 SBS RAL 7035 MG this is inserting as ENTREE D25 SBS RAL 7035 MG

I am generating the queries dynamically because each time my gridview columns will change.

```
For j = 1 To totcols - 1
    If Right(GridWFOwner.HeaderRow.Cells(j).Text, 4) = "PREV" Then

    ElseIf GridWFOwner.HeaderRow.Cells(j).Text = "CHANGE_INFO" Then

    Else
        SQL_COL = SQL_COL & "," & GridWFOwner.HeaderRow.Cells(j).Text

        SQL_VAL = SQL_VAL & ",LTRIM(RTRIM('" & Trim(Replace(Replace(Server.HtmlDecode(row.Cells(j).Text), "'", "''"), "&nbsp;", "")) & "'))"
    End If
Next

SQL_COL = Mid(SQL_COL, 2, Len(SQL_COL))
SQL_VAL = Mid(SQL_VAL, 2, Len(SQL_VAL))

SQL_COL = "ETL_ID," & SQL_COL & "," & "REQUEST_NO,DC_CODE,USER_ID,INSERT_TS"
If ACTION_FLAG = "I" Then
    TOT_SQL = "INSERT INTO DVLX.TABEL1(" & SQL_COL & ") VALUES(SEQ_MAT.NEXTVAL," & SQL_VAL & "," & "'" & uprno & "'" & ",'IBR'," & "'" & Session("user_id") & "'" & ",sysdate)"
Else
    TOT_SQL = "INSERT INTO DVLX.TABEL1(" & SQL_COL & ") VALUES(SEQ_MAT.NEXTVAL," & SQL_VAL & "," & "'" & uprno & "'" & ",'IBR'," & "'" & Session("user_id") & "'" & ",sysdate)"
End If

Dim cmdi As OracleCommand
cmdi = New OracleCommand(TOT_SQL, cnOra)
cmdi.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: Have you tried to print the sql command before execution?

Comment: This looks vulnerable to SQL injection, as you're building the command directly from user input - `row.Cells(j).Text`. Use parameterized queries.

Comment: @shingo I tried printing the sql command It was coming correctly, i executed the same query in oracle sql developer, it was inserted properly with french characters. But from .net it was going as english characters

Comment: Which provider do you use? What is the NLS_LANG value? You should use parameterized statements with bind variables.

Comment: What is the reason for the action_flag? I don't see any difference in the two statements.

Comment: I guess it's a charset problem: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535773/c-oracle-specify-encoding-character-set-of-query)